# Javascript regex look for a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling with javascript regex (regex in general actually).

I have a string of text looks like this,

`wall_treatment/S3/COOL_NEUTRAL/MMC_Walls_FC_S1_COOL_NEUTRAL_00000.png`

In the string above I want to look for a string that matches *Sn* (where n is a number). Is this possible?

Comment: Could it be `S12`, `S01` or even `S001003` ?

Comment: Could you explain why you need that? What are you doing with this path?

Answer (score 2):

```
var data="wall_treatment/S3/COOL_NEUTRAL/MMC_Walls_FC_S1_COOL_NEUTRAL_00000.png";
console.log(/S\d/.exec(data)[0]);
```

will give you the first match `S3`. If you want all the instances, you can do

```
console.log(data.match(/S\d/g));
```

will give all the matches and in this case it is

```
[ 'S3', 'S1' ]
```